# Drupal 7 Bootstrap Subtheme update

Tags: theming, bootstrap-theme

I'm trying to understand the flow of the bootstrap subtheme. The subtheme on my site was originally installed by a developer. I have since edited the css file to my liking and made adjustments to the bootstrap_subtheme.info, header.tpl.php, page.tpl.php, template.php and others.

The thing I don't understand is how to update the subtheme or even if I have to. I have been told by a developer that the bootstrap files are 5 years old. I apply each update as it comes into the list of updates and it is up to date in that respect. Do I have to update the subtheme manually from the basetheme? How do I find out the age/version of the subtheme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subtheme should inherit all of the basetheme files by default. So in theory you should be able to update the base bootstrap theme and your subtheme will gain all the benefits of those updates (Apart from things you're base theme has overwritten.)

E.g. if in bootstrap you have a page.tpl.php and you also have one in your subtheme then updating the bootstrap page.tpl.php won't have any effect as your subtheme has its own version of page.tpl.php

But anything that hasn't been overwritten/customised by your sub theme should be automatically be picked up by your subtheme. So you don't need to know what version your subtheme is, its effectly whatever the current bootstrap version is your subtheme is a ofshoot of that.

Comment: Would I then need to look at all the files in the subtheme that I have changed and compare them to the updated basetheme to see if the new releases have added new features into them, then incorporate them into customised files?

Comment: Depends you might not want those features e.g. some new styles or layout might mess up your stuff. Usually with themes unless theres a specific new bit of functionality or security update you want from the base theme then you dont really need to update it